# Enable link to work when textarea has less than 1000 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a form. When a user goes to my page, some of the form fields are hidden using css and the display:none property. The only fields that are shown are a link, image and a text area. I am trying to show the user the rest of the form when they click the link but only if the text area has less than 1000 characters.

**#promotion_image_description_block** is the textarea ID
**#promotion** is the href of the link.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
        if ($("#promotion_image_description_block").val().length >= 1000) {
            alert("This must be less than 1000 Characters!");
            return false;
        } else {
            switch ($(this).attr('href')) {
                case '#promotion':
                    $('#promotion_facebook_id_block, #promotion_name_block, #promotion_email_block, #promotion_address_1_block, #promotion_csz_block, #promotion_country_block, #promotion_phone_block, #promotion_custom_field_9_block, #promotion_custom_field_8_block, #promotion_custom_field_4_block, #promotion_custom_field_2_block, #promotion_custom_field_5_block, #promotion_custom_field_6_block, #promotion_custom_field_3_block, #promotion_agree_block, #promotion_submit_block, #disclaimer_promotion, #links2').show();
                    $('#promotion_custom_field_10_block, #promotion_image_description_block, #promotion_custom_field_11_block').hide();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This fix to having the alert show up:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/btedK/

Comment: Looks good, except that I'd use a common class rather than a huge list of IDs. What's the question?

Comment: The alert does not show up when over 1000 characters and the form is still revealed.

Comment: works: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm8LP/

Comment: works in my tests. could you post some html?
@ZachR Even your fiddle works for me, if i change the .size to .length in there...

Comment: Oops. I was missing an ID. Fiddle updated.

Comment: Yeah, it all works. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/btedK/

Comment: @isherwood your fiddle worked perfectly. I just added my other form elements and it works just fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't change anything in your code--just some simplification. You should put a solution in an answer below or delete your question since it doesn't offer anything of value without an answer.